# Converting/importing OSX's keyboard layout to Windows

Tags: windows, macos, keyboard-layout

Can an OSX .keylayout (created by Ukelele, but I think this doesn't matter) be somehow converted to be used under Windows?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, but maybe be a bit more specific: How do you want the OS X `cmd` and `alt` to be mapped to Windows exactly?

Comment: @slhck: true. assume "don't touch the modifiers".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thats not possible to do unfortunately. The only thing i can point you to is [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/goglobal/bb964665.aspx), which allows you to create a keyboard layout, all you would have to do is copy it